# Bounded Derivative on an Interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $ f : I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and suppose that $f'$ is bounded on $I$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $I$ .

I can do this using the Mean Value Theorem and the definition of uniform continuity. However that requires $f'$ to be continuous on the interval? Or is this a mistake in the question? All the other questions related on the forum they have the claim that $f'$ exists.

Answer (score 1):

No continuity of $f'$ is required. Rather, you can prove something stronger, $f$ is actually Lipschitz continuous: $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(c)||x-y|\leq(\sup|f'|)|x-y|$.

Comment: Can you expand on the difference between uniform and Lipschitz? Is it claiming that there is a maximum $\epsilon$?

Comment: Look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69457/an-example-of-a-function-uniformly-continuous-on-mathbbr-but-not-lipschitz), and also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3073665/showing-function-is-not-lipschitz-continuous).

Comment: Do I still need to claim an arbitrary closed interval $[x,y]$ for Lipschitz continuity? Or I need to anyways for the mean value basis?

Comment: I don't quite get what you said. But in your question, those $x,y$ can run within the interval $I$, because $\sup_{I}|f'|<\infty$.

Comment: My question is , for the mean value theorem we need $f $ to be continuous on$[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ how do we claim that in this instance?

Comment: I think in your question the so called $I$ must at least mean an interval. For suppose that $I=[a,b]$, the existence of the derivative $f'$ should include also the left-right derivatives too. For $I=(a,b)$, yes, maybe it is better to stress about the interval $[x,y]\subseteq(a,b)$ for $x<y$.

Comment: You can claim that the derivative exists because$f'$ is bounded? Is it not possible for there to be discontinuity in the derivative if it is bounded?

Comment: The problem says $f'$... on $I$, we must therefore interpret it as $f'$ exists for every point in $I$.